# Bot pausing during UAC panel popup

Tags: java, node.js, bots, uac

I tried different languages and libraries (Java Robot, NodeJS "nutjs" Robot) for automation but they all pause when the UAC window pops up.

I'm building a dedicated Windows device on which will run headless and graphical bot to do some task and at some point I need to use graphical applications but when I start them by double clicking on their icon (with or without the bot) I get the UAC panel which seems to run in a parallel universe in which my bot forgets its own existence.

I am running my bot as administator and it still can't interact with the UAC panel.

**Any languages/libraries I can use such that my bot can interact with the UAC to click YES?**

Comment: "Any languages/libraries I can use such that my bot can interact with the UAC to click YES?" No. If this were possible, then all malware would exploit this. If your program still requests elevation, then it's not actually running as administrator. (Logging on with an admin account is not the same as being elevated.)